# How do I run trade.sh script on hyperledger fabric?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

What the heck am I doing wrong? I cannot get the trade.sh script up....
Can I start it with docker-compose instead? How?

vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~/go/src/trade-finance-logistics/network$ ./trade.sh up
Starting with channel 'tradechannel'
Continue? [Y/n] Y
proceeding ...
**./trade.sh: line 138: configtxlator: command not found
Unable to find image 'hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.**
See 'docker run --help'.
LOCAL_VERSION=
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=

thanks fam

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The latest tag from the fabric docker images is removed. Use the tag 2.2 instead of the latest. Update the docker-compose file and change the image from **hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest to hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.2**